# Why we need to bind function in React Native?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am working on a React Native project. On some tutorials I have seen to bind a method like this:

```
constructor(props){
super(props);
this.my_function = this.my_function.bind(this);
}
```

My question is if I can access the function in constructor using `this.my_function` then why I need to bind this again? I have Java and Python background, may be that's why I am confused with this type of method binding.
Note: I know that if I don't bind a method in React Native/React JS my method won't work correctly. I just want to know why I need this extra binding.

Comment: there are a lot of tutorials regarding this, search for javascript context binding

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Take a look at this link to understand how JS closure works

http://yehudakatz.com/2011/08/11/understanding-javascript-function-invocation-and-this/

You need to bind the function so it has access to state and other variables in your class, not just parameters that pass when you execute.

Comment: great answer and a great reference that you gave - after reading the article i understand that the default 'this' in a  class function  refers to the function itself, the bind function overrides it to the object

Answer (score 3):

Well you need to bind `this` to the methods of the class. So that you can access a copy of the obj in the method body.

The special parameter `this` will automatically be available in the body of the method if it is called like that.

obj.my_function();

In this case, obj is passed to `this` parameter and you can access all the methods and properties of it using `obj.propertyName`.

But in your case, you class method `my_function` will most probably be called in result of an event of something. You need to bind the an instance of the class with this example.

Hope it helps.

I highly recommend going through this [resource](https://yehudakatz.com/2011/08/11/understanding-javascript-function-invocation-and-this/) for better understanding. Also mentioned in earlier answers.

Answer (score 2):

You will be using es6 classes in react so class will be having his own methods and variables. All this methods will be available in `this` and if one method wants to access another method of class that wont have access to `this` for giving access of `this` we need to `bind(this)` to that method.

If you are lazy then you can use arrow function that will automatically bind `this`.

```
class helloWorld extends Component {
     foo = () => {
        console.log(this);
     }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

IMHO it 's all about scopes and context in javascript. Understanding deeply how works the scopes in javascript allow you to build more powerfull applications and cleaner code.

Basically, bind allow you to stick a function to a given context. It's allow you to access to values stored in a specific Scope, in ReactJs the constructor scope generally.

You can read that also, a great article passing in review the bind method.

http://reactkungfu.com/2015/07/why-and-how-to-bind-methods-in-your-react-component-classes/

See also this discussion, maybe it will be usefull for you :

https://stackoverflow.com/a/38334183/9638302