# onChange doesn't work with mobile? - React Native

Tags: javascript, react-native

Right now I am trying to make a Log In Page and I've been using React Native to do so. It works perfectly fine on a web browser but when I try it on my phone, onChange doesn't seem to change the state of the password and username.

```
import React from 'react';
import { TextInput, View, TouchableOpacity, Text } from 'react-native';


class LogIn extends React.Component {
    
    constructor(props){
      super(props);
      this.state={
        username: 'John Doe',
        password: 'abc123'
      }
    }
    loginChangeHandler = (event) =>{
      this.setState({[event.target.name]: event.target.value});
    }
  
    loginButtonHandler = () =>{
      
      alert('username: '+this.state.username+ ' Password: '+this.state.password)
    }
    render() {
        return (
         
          <View  style = {{alignItems: 'center'}}>
          
          <TextInput name = 'username' onChange  = {this.loginChangeHandler}
            placeholder = 'username'
            style={{ width: 200, height: 55, borderColor: 'gray', borderWidth: 1 }}
          />
          <Text>{'\n'}</Text>
          <TextInput name = 'password' onChange  = {this.loginChangeHandler} secureTextEntry={true}
            placeholder = 'password'
            style={{ width: 200, height: 55, borderColor: 'gray', borderWidth: 1 }}
          />
          <Text>{'\n'}</Text>
          <TouchableOpacity onPress = {this.loginButtonHandler} style = {{height: 45, width: 200, justifyContent: 'center',  alignItems: "center", backgroundColor: 'green'}}>
          <Text style = {{fontSize: 16, color: 'white'}}>LOG IN</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
          
          
          </View>
          
        );
      }
}




export default LogIn;
```

Comment: Try using onInput instead, since key events, on Android at least, aren't final, and the result text may change after another key press, like the case in Japanese and Chinese keyboards

Comment: hello, you should try to bind context this.loginChangeHandler.bind(this)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use `this` inside of a function you must bind the function with `this` object. Other thing is there isn't direct `name` prop for `TextInput` component and `event.target` is not returning something you expected. onChange is called with `{ nativeEvent: { eventCount, target, text} }`, then i suggest you to use `onChangeText` callback. This callback is called with only the value which you are typing.

Change your code this way.

```
render() {
        return (
         
          <View  style = {{alignItems: 'center'}}>
          
          <TextInput name = 'username' onChangeText= {(value) => this.setState({ username : value })}
            placeholder = 'username'
            style={{ width: 200, height: 55, borderColor: 'gray', borderWidth: 1 }}
          />
          <Text>{'\n'}</Text>
          <TextInput name = 'password' onChangeText={(value) => this.setState({ password : value })} secureTextEntry={true}
            placeholder = 'password'
            style={{ width: 200, height: 55, borderColor: 'gray', borderWidth: 1 }}
          />
          <Text>{'\n'}</Text>
          <TouchableOpacity onPress = {this.loginButtonHandler.bind(this)} style = {{height: 45, width: 200, justifyContent: 'center',  alignItems: "center", backgroundColor: 'green'}}>
          <Text style = {{fontSize: 16, color: 'white'}}>LOG IN</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
          
          
          </View>
          
        );
      }
```

Comment: Here's a an article that can make you more realize. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50726014/why-we-need-to-bind-function-in-react-native

Comment: Yes, you have made some other mistakes. I changed the answer. Have a look.