# purpose of having .bind()

Tags: reactjs

I can't understand why to use .bind() operation in the react applications. I noticed that most of the developers use it in their codes.And also without that operation i got errors. After adding that bind() operation successfully compile the code. but i don't know why to use that and what kind of thing done by that .bind() operation.(i got that code from the internet)

//App.js

```
 import React, { Component } from 'react';
    import logo from './resources/metro-library-3.jpg';
    import './App.css';
    import Table from './components/bookTable.js';
    import Footer from './components/footer.js';
    import Header from './components/header.js';

    class App extends Component {

        constructor(props){
            super(props); 
            this.setSelectedAuthor = this.setSelectedAuthor.bind(this);
            this.updateFooter = this.updateFooter.bind(this);

            this.state = {
                authors: [],
                selectedAuthor: "select author",
                footerBook: {
                    name: "",
                    author: ""
                }
            }

        }

        setSelectedAuthor(author){
            this.setState({
                selectedAuthor: author
            }, () =>{
                this.setState({selectedAuthor: author});
                console.log(this.state.selectedAuthor);
            })
             console.log(author);

        }

        updateFooter(book){
            this.setState({
                footerBook: book
            })
    }


    componentDidMount(){
        let url = 'http://localhost:8083/getAll';
        let auth = [];
        fetch(url).then(response => response.json()).then((data) => {
            data.bdata.map((book) =>{
                auth.push(book.author)
            })
            this.setState({
                authors: auth
            })
        })
    }
     render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
          <select value={this.state.selectedAuthor} onChange={(e) => this.setSelectedAuthor(e.target.value)}>
              <option value="select author">Select Author</option>
              {
                  this.state.authors.map((author, key) =>
                      <option key={key} value={author}>{author}</option>
                  )
              }
          </select>
          <Table filterBook = {this.state.selectedAuthor} update = {this.updateFooter}/>
          <Footer book={this.state.footerBook}/>

      </div>
    );
     }
    }

    export default App;
```

//AppContainer.js

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {BrowserRouter as Router} from 'react-router-dom';
import Route from 'react-router-dom/Route'
import App from '../App';
import Header from '../components/header.js';
import AddBooks from "../components/AddBooks";

class AppContainer extends Component{
    render(){
        return(
            <Router>
                <div>
                    <Route path = "/" component={Header}/>
                    <Route exact path = "/" component={App}/>
                    <Route exact path = "/addBook" component={AddBooks}/>
                </div>
            </Router>
        );
    }
}

export default AppContainer;
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [why do you need to bind a function in a constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38334062/why-do-you-need-to-bind-a-function-in-a-constructor)

Comment: There are at least 3 other ways to do the same without `bind`. To understand why we have to `bind` means you have to understand how `this` works in Javascript functions.

Answer (score 0):

@Chamali Read this to know.

**Binding functions**

Bounded function in JavaScript is a function that is bounded to a given context. That means no matter how you call it, the context of the call will stay the same. The only exception is the new operator which always return a new context.

To create a bounded function out of the regular function, the bind method is used. bind method take context to which you want to bind your function as a first argument. The rest of arguments are arguments that will be always passed to such function. It returns a bounded function as a result. Let’s see an example:

```
function add(x, y) {
  this.result += x + y;
}

var computation1 = { result: 0 };
var boundedAdd = add.bind(computation1);

boundedAdd(1, 2); // `this` is set to `computation1`.
                  //  computation1 after call: { result: 3 }

var boundedAddPlusTwo = add.bind(computation1, 2);
boundedAddPlusTwo(4); // `this` is set to `computation1`.
                      // computation1 after call: { result: 9 }
```

Bounded function can’t be changed even by manually calling call and apply! See these examples:

```
var obj = { boundedPlusTwo: boundedAddPlusTwo };
obj.boundedPlusTwo(4); // `this` is set to `computation1`.
                       // even though method is called on `obj`.
                       // computation1 after call: { result: 15 }
var computation2 = { result: 0 };
boundedAdd.call(computation2, 1, 2); // `this` is set to `computation1`.
                                 // even though context passed to call is
                                 // `computation2`
                                 // computation1 after call: { result: 18 }
```

You are now equipped with this knowledge about the JavaScript. Let’s jump to your React component classes and see how function call context affects your code.

[More details](http://reactkungfu.com/2015/07/why-and-how-to-bind-methods-in-your-react-component-classes/)

[React Binding Patterns: 5 Approaches for Handling `this`](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/react-binding-patterns-5-approaches-for-handling-this-92c651b5af56)

Hope this clears your doubt.

Answer (score 0):

The TL:DR version is that it sets the App class method's context to be the same as the App class context. Uses: `this.setState`, `this.props`, etc...