# What bind(this) is actually doing in ReactJS?

Tags: reactjs, react-state-management

```
this.something = this.something.bind(this)
```

What is the above line actually doing? I am a newbie so please give a elementary level of explanation(for my understanding) also in a  technical way

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Use of the JavaScript 'bind' method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2236747/use-of-the-javascript-bind-method)

Comment: you dont have to use bind though, ex: onClick={this.doSomething}, if defined as onClick={() => this.doSomething()} it will work without it

Comment: @thsorens i got your's can you explain still more technically

Answer (score 0):

#### What is the above line actually doing?

[Use of the JavaScript 'bind' method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2236747/use-of-the-javascript-bind-method)

> `bind` creates a new function that will have this set to the first parameter passed to `bind()`.

This is necessary because in the DOM library and many parts of JavaScript the hidden/implicit `this` function parameter is changed to point to different objects behind-the-scenes.

A good example concerns event-handlers in JavaScript, where the `this` parameter is not what it seems:

HTML:

```
<button id="someButton" name="Bar">Hello</button>
```

JavaScript (run after DOM is loaded):

```
function Foo() {
    this.name = "Foo";
}
Foo.prototype.eventHandler( event ) {
    console.log( event.type ); // will always print "click"
    console.log( this.name ); // will print either "Foo" or "Bar"
}

var button = document.getElementById("someButton"); // HTMLButton

var fooInstance = new Foo(); // fooInstance.name == "Foo"

button.addEventListener( 'click', fooInstance.eventHandler );
```

If you run this code and click the button and set a breakpoint in `Foo.prototype.eventHandler` then you'll see that `this.name` is `"Bar"` and not `"Foo"` - even though you passed in a reference to `fooInstance.eventHandler` which surely knows about `fooInstance` when invoked?

It doesn't.

This is because the DOM API changes the `this` of `fooInstance.eventHandler` to be the `button` instance instead. I don't know the exact reason, but I believe it's related to maintaining backwards compatibility with old-school HTML-attribute based JavaScript event-handlers like these:

```
<button onclick="alert(this.name)" name="Baz">Click me</button>
```

(Where `this` refers to the containing `HTMLElement`)

So using `.bind` *overrides* the library's changing of `this`. You might think that as `.bind(this)` returns another `Function` that the `this` parameter will be changed anyway, but in fact, it doesn't. This is because the `Function` returned actually cannot have its `this` member changed at all, unlike most `Function` objects.

#### In ReactJS:

The use of `foo = foo.bind(this)` isn't anything unique to ReactJS (it's part of JavaScript) but it is an idiom in ReactJS:

[why do you need to bind a function in a constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38334062/why-do-you-need-to-bind-a-function-in-a-constructor)

> This is because React didn't want to mess with ES6 specifications (binding this to functions from its class is not in the ES6 class spec), but at the same time, wanted to give its users the convenience of ES6 class syntax. You can read more about this below.