# Reactjs function binding on event handler

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I'm trying to understand why we have to bind an object null to the function

```
add(text) {
    this.setState(prevState=> ({
        notes: [
            ...prevState.notes,
            {
                id: this.nextId(),
                note: text
            }
        ]
    }))
}

render() {
    return (
        <div className="board">
            {this.state.notes.map(this.eachNote)}
            <button onClick={this.add.bind(null, "New Note")}
                id="add">Add note</button>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Why can't we just do `this.add("New Note")` ?

Comment: is it working as expected after adding null?

Comment: Possible duplicate of this [link], you can get an explanation from this link
(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38334062/why-do-you-need-to-bind-a-function-in-a-constructor)

Comment: Passing `null` shouldn't work . Are you sure it does?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`onClick={this.add("New Note")}` would immediately run the `add()` method, then set the result as `onClick`. The result of `add()` is undefined, because it doesn't return anything. So we'd essentially do `onClick={undefined}`.

So to fix that, we can use an anonymous function: `onClick={() => this.add("New Note")}`
This time, the program properly calls `this.add("New Note")` when the button is clicked.

Or we can just take advantage of the fact that `bind()` allows us to state the `this` context and the arguments we want to pass, and simply use `onClick={this.add.bind(this, "New Note")}` (using `this` as first argument binds the instance as context, just like the arrow function in the 2nd paragraph)