# Why is the this keyword inside clickHandler undefined?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, object, event-handling, this

I was following a YouTube tutorial on eventHandling when I got confused with the implementation of **this** keyword.

In the code below, the **this** keyword inside of clickHandler function gives the value of undefined. The instructor said that it is because that's how JavaScript works. But when I searched online I found out that **this** keyword when used inside a function of a class, points to the object itself.

This might be a stupid question to ask but since I am new to JavaScript any help will be appreciated

```
class EventBind extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      message: "Hello",
    };
  }

  clickHandler() {
    // this.setState({
    //   message : 'Goodbye'
    // })
    console.log(this);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div>{this.state.message}</div>
        <button onClick = {this.clickHandler}>Click</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is cause you have not bound the `clickHandler` to `this`.
Try below code

```
class EventBind extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.clickHandler = this.clickHandler.bind(this);
    ...

  }
  clickHandler() {
    ...
  }
  ...
  
}
```

See here for more info: https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-functions.html

Comment: You can use arrow functions to avoid this explicit binding.

Comment: Can you clarify why binding is not necessary in this example https://www.vojtechruzicka.com/javascript-this-keyword/#in-classes. Thanks

Comment: @PrajwalAdhikari I believe the answer you are looking for is explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38334062/why-do-you-need-to-bind-a-function-in-a-constructor