# Touchstart eventhandler returns event undefined

Tags: javascript, vue.js

```
@touchstart="touchStart(event)"

touchStart(event) {
      console.log(event);
      console.log("touch start");
    }
```

Why is event returnung undefined?

Comment: It's `$event`, not just `event`

Answer (score 0):

Events are executed in a different context from which they are defined. Hence we need to bind them to the object which it is attached to. React code will have a lot of these binding statements. Look it up for more details

[why do you need to bind a function in a constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38334062/why-do-you-need-to-bind-a-function-in-a-constructor)